# Create a list in Views of non-node pages created in Views and Custom Pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-panels

I have a fairly large enterprise site and I am needing to create a dynamic HTML site map. Similar to the [site map at Apple](http://www.apple.com/sitemap).

With that in mind, I have created a view that lists all node-based pages (i.e.) those pages created and associated with a content type. The problem is that many of the pages on the site are pages created in Views or in Custom Pages and the url is defined there. These aren't dynamic pages, rather they are pages built to  be main pages for different sections.

Example: the site has a team content type. This content holds information about an employe. The page at the node level is site.com/team/john-doe. I've set up a view page with the url site.com/team - This lists the name and a photo of the team member.

This is the case for many sections on the site, since these are important pages I need to somehow create a view that lists these pages so I can then take that view content pane and the node-based content pages and drop that into a custom page to build the HTML site map.

Since these custom pages aren't stored in the db I am not sure how I can get views to extract that data and render it as a list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking to achieve is going to be driven more by menus than by views or nodes, custom or otherwise. The menu system contains references to all paths on the site, whether they were created by nodes, views, taxonomies, custom code, etc.

You might find the Menu Views module useful for this:
http://drupal.org/project/menu_views

For a slightly different approach, I would also suggest looking at the Site Map module: 
http://drupal.org/project/site_map